# Why does Autofs create a new folder when mounting?

Tags: mount, cifs, autofs

autofs

mounts my CIFS shares like this:

```
/mnt/server1/server1
/mnt/server2/server2
```

While I want it to be just:

```
/mnt/server1
/mnt/server2
```

I have in auto.master:

```
/mnt/server1 /etc/auto.server1 --timeout=6000 --ghost
/mnt/server2 /etc/auto.server2 --timeout=6000 --ghost
```

In auto.server1:

```
server1    -fstype=cifs,uid=1000,gid=1000,forceuid,forcegid,credentials=/etc/auto.auth    ://10.0.0.10/share
```

In auto.server2:

```
server2    -fstype=cifs,uid=1000,gid=1000,forceuid,forcegid,credentials=/etc/auto.auth    ://10.0.0.20/share
```

Keep in mind that everything works, except that it creates this server1/server1 structure. I've tried to just remove "server" from auto.server1, but that makes it fail to work. I've also tried to change "/mnt/server1" (and 2) in auto.master to just "/mnt", but that also makes it fail to work.

Is there some option or argument I need to enable or disable to stop it from making this extra directory? How do I tell autofs plain and simply to mount it  without any additional directory being created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configuration you have is called [indirect maps](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Autofs#The_Master_Map_File):

> Indirect maps, create-mount points as subdirectories inside the main mount-point.

in this configuration, you are telling autofs in the `auto.master` file:

```
/mnt/server /etc/auto.server --timeout=6000 --ghost
```

to look in `/etc/auto.server` and mount under the main mount point of `/mnt/server` (not `/mnt`) ... and in the `auto.server` file you have:

```
server    -fstype=cifs,uid=1000,gid=1000,forceuid,forcegid,credentials=/etc/auto.auth    ://10.0.0.10/share
```

`server` being the name(of this mount point) ... so you get the expected result of:

```
/mnt/server/server
```

**Change** your `auto.master` line to:

```
/mnt /etc/auto.server --timeout=6000 --ghost
```

and you will get what you want:

```
/mnt/server
```

**Furthermore**, why use two files `autu.server1` and `auto.server2` for the same main mount point and why two lines in `auto.master` for the same main mount point … combine the two files in one `auto.server` file with two lines like so:

```
server1    -fstype=cifs,uid=1000,gid=1000,forceuid,forcegid,credentials=/etc/auto.auth    ://10.0.0.10/share
server2    -fstype=cifs,uid=1000,gid=1000,forceuid,forcegid,credentials=/etc/auto.auth    ://10.0.0.20/share
```

and make the two lines in `auto.master` into just one line referencing `auto.server` like so:

```
/mnt /etc/auto.server --timeout=6000 --ghost
```

then, run :

```
sudo service autofs reload
```

to read the new changes.

#### Important notice:

Don't use any **main mount-point** that you specify in `auto.master` with another mount service e.g. the default Ubuntu [Disk Manager `udisks`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man8/udisks.8.html) that is involved in user automatic(when connecting a USB disk) or manual(when clicking on the mount button in the GUI file manager or when issuing a `mount ...` command in the terminal).

[`automount`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man8/automount.8.html) is the program used to configure a mount point for `autofs`. When `autofs` is started, an `automount` daemon is spawned for each map.

As you can see these are two different system services/animal species(*metaphorically speaking*) ... if you point them at each others mount point/food(*again metaphorically*), they will fight and this would cause conflicts and casualties(*metaphorically again*) and one of them(or both) will loose ... and you don't want that.

Therefor, use a separate mount points for each of these services ... you can either use readily available mount points like `/mnt` and `/media` or create your own mount point/s with like `mkdir ~/my_mnt` and use it with like `mount device ~/my_mnt` ... everyone will be happier this way :)

Comment: I simplified my problem to give the minimal reproducible example (I didn't realize that my issue might be related to having two entries); I actually have two entries in auto.master, and when I change both to be just /mnt, only the first one works. For just one entry, your solution works though.

Comment: @AlphaCentauri Why two files `autu.server1` and `auto. server2` on the same main mount point and why two lines in `auto.master` for the same main mount point … combine the two files in one `auto.server` file with two lines and make the two lines in `auto.master` into just one line referencing `auto.server` then run `sudo service autofs reload` to read the new changes.

Comment: This almost works, the only problem now, is that all my other mount points disappear under /mnt. I do get /mnt/server1 and /mnt/server2 as I want, however, I no longer have /mnt/tmp /mnt/sdc /mnt/loop.

Comment: @AlphaCentauri You probably have them in separate files e.g. `auto.tmp`, `auto.sdc` and `auto.loop` ... You need to add their contents as separate lines beneath the already existing two lines in `auto.server` and remove the old references to those files in `auto.master` then reload the autofs service and then you'll have them back again.

Comment: No those I mount manually when I (rarely) need them.

Comment: @AlphaCentaur That wold cause conflicts… ether add them to autofs to be automatically mounted or create a separate mount point like `mkdir ~/my_mnt` to manually mount them under it … you can also choose to change autofs main mount-point instead from `/mnt` to a new mount point  so you can manually mount under `/mnt` … either choices will work fine.

Comment: So basically, if you intend to use autofs under a particular directory, like /mnt, then make sure nothing else uses /mnt.

Comment: @AlphaCentauri Updated the answer for [that one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1414780/why-does-autofs-create-a-new-folder-when-mounting#comment2460973_1414783)